# Vertex AI seems to think a deployed model input shape is different then when predicting locally

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm getting what I see as strange behavior out of a deployed model in vertex ai.  I have a CNN model built with tensorflow/keras version 2.7.  My input data is a 3 dimensional array with the follow shape (1, 570, 33).  When I pass the input data to the model locally I have a correct response.

```
model = keras.models.load_model('model')
x = model.predict(input_data) # input_data is a numpy array of shape (1, 570, 33)   
print(x)
[[0.1259355  0.9124526  0.65782744 0.2628207 ]]
```

This is a correct prediction and the model does what it is trained to do.  No problems

When I upload the model to Vertex AI using the prebuilt Tensorflow 2.7 docker container with no extra settings (no acceleration for example) and deploy that model to an endpoint this is what I get when I call predict with the same input_data formatted for Vertex AI.

```
resp = client.predict(
    endpoint=endpoint_path,
    instances=input_data.toList(),
    parameters=parameters,
)

input must be 4-dimensional[1,570,33]\n\t [[{{function_node __inference__wrapped_model_28143}}{{node sequential/conv2d/BiasAdd}}]]
```

Here is the summary of of the model

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 570, 33, 32)       320       
                                                                
batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 570, 33, 32)      128       
ormalization)                                                   
                                                                
activation (Activation)     (None, 570, 33, 32)       0         
                                                                
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 570, 33, 32)       9248      
                                                                
batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 570, 33, 32)      128       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_1 (Activation)   (None, 570, 33, 32)       0         
                                                                
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 570, 33, 32)       9248      
                                                                
batch_normalization_2 (Batc  (None, 570, 33, 32)      128       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_2 (Activation)   (None, 570, 33, 32)       0         
                                                                
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 285, 17, 64)       18496     
                                                                
batch_normalization_3 (Batc  (None, 285, 17, 64)      256       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_3 (Activation)   (None, 285, 17, 64)       0         
                                                                
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 285, 17, 64)       36928     
                                                                
batch_normalization_4 (Batc  (None, 285, 17, 64)      256       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_4 (Activation)   (None, 285, 17, 64)       0         
                                                                
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)           (None, 285, 17, 64)       36928     
                                                                
batch_normalization_5 (Batc  (None, 285, 17, 64)      256       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_5 (Activation)   (None, 285, 17, 64)       0         
                                                                
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 285, 17, 64)       36928     
                                                                
batch_normalization_6 (Batc  (None, 285, 17, 64)      256       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_6 (Activation)   (None, 285, 17, 64)       0         
                                                                
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 143, 9, 96)        55392     
                                                                
batch_normalization_7 (Batc  (None, 143, 9, 96)       384       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_7 (Activation)   (None, 143, 9, 96)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 143, 9, 96)        83040     
                                                                
batch_normalization_8 (Batc  (None, 143, 9, 96)       384       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_8 (Activation)   (None, 143, 9, 96)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)           (None, 143, 9, 96)        83040     
                                                                
batch_normalization_9 (Batc  (None, 143, 9, 96)       384       
hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                
activation_9 (Activation)   (None, 143, 9, 96)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 143, 9, 96)        83040     
                                                                
batch_normalization_10 (Bat  (None, 143, 9, 96)       384       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_10 (Activation)  (None, 143, 9, 96)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)          (None, 72, 5, 128)        110720    
                                                                
batch_normalization_11 (Bat  (None, 72, 5, 128)       512       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_11 (Activation)  (None, 72, 5, 128)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_12 (Conv2D)          (None, 72, 5, 128)        147584    
                                                                
batch_normalization_12 (Bat  (None, 72, 5, 128)       512       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_12 (Activation)  (None, 72, 5, 128)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_13 (Conv2D)          (None, 72, 5, 128)        147584    
                                                                
batch_normalization_13 (Bat  (None, 72, 5, 128)       512       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_13 (Activation)  (None, 72, 5, 128)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_14 (Conv2D)          (None, 72, 5, 128)        147584    
                                                                
batch_normalization_14 (Bat  (None, 72, 5, 128)       512       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_14 (Activation)  (None, 72, 5, 128)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_15 (Conv2D)          (None, 36, 3, 160)        184480    
                                                                
batch_normalization_15 (Bat  (None, 36, 3, 160)       640       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_15 (Activation)  (None, 36, 3, 160)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_16 (Conv2D)          (None, 36, 3, 160)        230560    
                                                                
batch_normalization_16 (Bat  (None, 36, 3, 160)       640       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_16 (Activation)  (None, 36, 3, 160)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_17 (Conv2D)          (None, 36, 3, 160)        230560    
                                                                
batch_normalization_17 (Bat  (None, 36, 3, 160)       640       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_17 (Activation)  (None, 36, 3, 160)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_18 (Conv2D)          (None, 36, 3, 160)        230560    
                                                                
batch_normalization_18 (Bat  (None, 36, 3, 160)       640       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_18 (Activation)  (None, 36, 3, 160)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_19 (Conv2D)          (None, 18, 2, 192)        276672    
                                                                
batch_normalization_19 (Bat  (None, 18, 2, 192)       768       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_19 (Activation)  (None, 18, 2, 192)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_20 (Conv2D)          (None, 18, 2, 192)        331968    
                                                                
batch_normalization_20 (Bat  (None, 18, 2, 192)       768       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_20 (Activation)  (None, 18, 2, 192)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)          (None, 18, 2, 192)        331968    
                                                                
batch_normalization_21 (Bat  (None, 18, 2, 192)       768       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_21 (Activation)  (None, 18, 2, 192)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)          (None, 18, 2, 192)        331968    
                                                                
batch_normalization_22 (Bat  (None, 18, 2, 192)       768       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_22 (Activation)  (None, 18, 2, 192)        0         
                                                                
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)          (None, 9, 1, 224)         387296    
                                                                
batch_normalization_23 (Bat  (None, 9, 1, 224)        896       
chNormalization)                                                
                                                                
activation_23 (Activation)  (None, 9, 1, 224)         0         
                                                                
reshape (Reshape)           (None, 9, 224)            0         
                                                                
masking (Masking)           (None, 9, 224)            0         
                                                                
lambda (Lambda)             (None, 224)               0         
                                                                
dense (Dense)               (None, 4)                 900       
                                                                
=================================================================
Total params: 3,554,532
Trainable params: 3,548,772
Non-trainable params: 5,760
```

I've got a classic case of 'It works on my machine' here and could use any input or help :)

Answer (score 1):

When using Vertex Prediction service with Tensorflow models, following is the expected format of input request as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/online-predictions-custom-models#tensorflow)

```
{
  "instances": [
    <value>|<simple/nested list>|<object>,
    ...
  ]
}
```

For your scenario, try with

```
{
  "instances": [
    [
      [
        [138, 30, 66, ...],
        [130, 20, 56, ...],
        ...
      ],
      [
        [126, 38, 61, ...],
        [122, 24, 57, ...],
        ...
      ],
      ...
    ],
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: first thank you for taking the time to answer my question.  Your example is exactly how I have my instances setup when trying to hit the endpoint.  Sending instances to the predict endpoint of the model using the builtin tensorflow container causes the invalid dimension error, where as if I execute the predict function locally on my machine with the same data I get a valid prediction.

Comment: One other data point.  I created a custom container with my model on it, imported that container as my model, associated that model with an endpoint in vertex ai and sent the data to it (exact format you posted) and the prediction came back perfectly.